# PHP slim Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Route pattern must be a string'

Tags: php, json, slim

This is the line of code I am using to map the URL pattern to function in the index.php page in slim:

```
$app->POST("/signup","signup");
```

Why does the console output say:

> Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Route
>   pattern must be a string' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\php-slim\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\Router.php:169

despite the pattern being defined as `/signup`.

I am calling localhost:8080/php-slim/signup from POSTMAN.

**Console output :**
[image]

Comment: What is your PHP and Slim Framework version? Can you post `index.php` content? The exception is triggered because somehow `is_string()` function returns false which is weird because it is supposed to contain value '/signup' which is should be string. This may be a bug in PHP for Windows or Slim but I cannot reproduce the issue.

Comment: i did a clean re-install of the entire lim framework, and this issue got resolved